# On correspondence of random function and stochastic processes

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

By reading Billingsly book on convergence of probability measures I was led to believe the following,

Given a random function $X:\Omega \rightarrow \mathcal{X} $ we obtain the stochastic processes $(X_{t})_{t \in T}$ by considering $X_{t}=\pi_{t}\circ X$ where  $\pi_{t} :\mathcal{X}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is the point evaluation functional for some function space $\mathcal{X}$ (where $X$ takes its values).

Can we obtain any stochastic process of this way if we choose the right $\mathcal{X}$?

Comment: Sure, try $\mathcal X=\mathbb R^T$.

Comment: @Did ah I tought that it was only continuous function in that space. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just take $\mathcal{X}=R^{T}$.